# Laravel homestead ignores features to be installed

Tags: laravel, homestead

I want to add Minio to my Homestead VM. I've added the features option to the `homestead.yml` file, but running `vagrant reload --provision` doens't change anything and visiting `http://homestead:9600/` gives me a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. What am I missing here?

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 4096
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
name: ausbildungsportal

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:

    - map: E:\programierung\ausbildungslink
      to: /home/vagrant/code/ausbildungslink

    - map: E:\programierung\uptimechecker
      to: /home/vagrant/code/uptimechecker

sites:

    - map: azubi.tested
      to: /home/vagrant/code/uptimechecker/public

    - map: help.tested
      to: /home/vagrant/code/ausbildungslink/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - azubiportal
    - ausbildungslink

features:
  - minio: true
```

Comment: Have you completed the setup, by changing your `config/filesystems.php` and adding your AWS options to the `.env` file?  As detailed here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#configuring-minio

Comment: No, but normally I should access the web dashboard in the browser. But I can’t access the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it and it didn't work for me. Fixed it by updating to the latest version of homestead

> composer require laravel/homestead

Comment: I thought I've updated my homestead, but it was only the vagrant box. Thanks for pointing that out! It worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same issue, leaving my solution here just in case.

For each feature, a separate script is triggered to manage the installation.
E.g. for docker it is *homestead/scripts/features/docker.sh*.
Inside it is checking if the feature is already installed (may look slightly different depending on the version):

```
if [ -f /home/$WSL_USER_NAME/.homestead-features/docker ]
then
    echo "docker already installed."
    exit 0
fi
```

So, if the feature is not installed, but still ignored by the Homestead script, you can just delete the needed file inside the VM (e.g. */home/vagrant/.homestead-features/docker* for docker feature, similar for other features).